# Export Data in excel and then import from excel using PHP. DB is MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import, export

--I have some rows from my table which I would like to export in excel format. This step is equivalent to the user enters the search criteria and all matching rows will be exported in an excel file.

--The user makes changes to the excel file. Add or update rows.

--The user upload the file and all updated rows gets updated in the database and all added rows gets added in the database.

All this I want to do in PHP and the database it is using is MySQL. Servers are running Linux (no COM!)

I have exporting and importing part I explained above done seperately.

I am using [PHPExcelReader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) to read the file and save it. But that requires the user to download the template first, copy data from exported excel and paste it in the template.

For exporting, I am just creating a simple HTML table and fool the browser, its an excel! 
Excel will open HTML table but ofcourse while saving that file, it will change the format and make it valid excel file.

Please throw some ideas on how can I make it work? :/

Thank you ... I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you PHPExcel library.

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

You can do import, export, pdf, etc. I think this is a great library.

Comment: Biggest benefit... it's a single library for both writing and for reading xls files, and as OP needs to do both, that makes it a better choice than going for separate incompatible libraries for reading and for writing

Answer (score 1):

**

- **EXPORTING PURPOSE**

**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("school");
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/exp_stdsub.js"></script>
    </head>
       <hr />
                            <u><h3>Export your Data here</h3></u>
                            <form action="" method="post"> 
                                        <select name="expstd" id="expstd" onclick="return expsubjs(this.value);">
                                            <option>Select Standared</option>
                                    <?php
                                        $exe_sel_std = mysql_query("SELECT * from s_standared");
                                        while($r_sel_std = mysql_fetch_array($exe_sel_std)){
                                            $sel_stdid = $r_sel_std['std_id'];
                                            $sel_std = $r_sel_std['std']; ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $sel_stdid; ?>"><?php echo $sel_std; ?></option>
                                            <?php  } ?>
                                            </select></td>


                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green" name="exp_stdque" value="Export Standardwise Question">

                            </form>
                        </table>

<?php

//EDIT YOUR MySQL Connection Info:
$DB_Server = "localhost";        //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "root";                 //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "";                //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "school";                //your MySQL Database Name
$DB_TBLName = "s_question";                //your MySQL Table Name

if(isset($_POST['exp_stdque'])) {
    $exstdid = $_POST['expstd'];

//$DB_TBLName,  $DB_DBName, may also be commented out & passed to the browser
//as parameters in a query string, so that this code may be easily reused for
//any MySQL table or any MySQL database on your server

//DEFINE SQL QUERY:
//edit this to suit your needs
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE std_id = $exstdid";

//Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
//for when file was generated:
//set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
$Use_Title = 1;
//define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
$now_date = DATE('m-d-Y H:i');
//define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
$title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";
/*

Leave the connection info below as it is:
just edit the above.

(Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
*/
//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @MYSQL_CONNECT($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
     or DIE("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR() . "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//select database
$Db = @MYSQL_SELECT_DB($DB_DBName, $Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't select database:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//execute query
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}ELSE {
     $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
     $file_ending = "xls";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=database_dump.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character

     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
         //define field names
         $field_name = MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$j);
         //will show name of fields
         $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 }
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 }
             ELSE {
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                 }
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         //end of each mysql row
         //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
         PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
     }
}ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < MYSQL_NUM_FIELDS($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";
     }
}
}

?>
```

**`IMPORTING FROM EXCEL INTO MySQL USING PHP`**

```
<table>
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
                            <tr>
                            <td><h5><b>Select Standared</b></h5></td>
                            <td><select name="chap_sel_std" id="chap_sel_std">
                                                        <option>Select Standared</option>
                                                <?php
                                                    $exe_sel_std = mysql_query("SELECT * from s_standared");
                                                    while($r_sel_std = mysql_fetch_array($exe_sel_std)){
                                                        $sel_stdid = $r_sel_std['std_id'];
                                                        $sel_std = $r_sel_std['std'];?>

                                                        <option value="<?php echo $sel_stdid; ?>"><?php echo $sel_std;?></option>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5><b>Select Font</b></h5></td>
                                <td><select name="sel_f_gn_que">
                                    <option>Select Font</option>
                                        <?php
                                            $xf = mysql_query("SELECT * from s_font");
                                            while($rquef = mysql_fetch_array($xf)){
                                                $f_id = $rquef['f_id'];
                                                $f_name = $rquef['f_name'];  ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $f_id; ?>"><?php echo $f_name; }?>  </option>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5><b>Upload Question<h5><b></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="btn">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-green big" name="add_que" value="Add Questions"></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="saveandexit" class="" value="Finish" onclick="close();"></td>
                            </tr>
                    </form>
                    </table>
                    </div>                   

    <?php

            $data = array();

    //$db =& DB::connect("mysql://root@localhost/names", array());
    //if (PEAR::isError($db)) { die($db->getMessage()); }
      //quetype    difficulty    standard    subject    chap    que    marks

    function add_person($quetype,$dif, $subject,$chap_name,$que,$marks)
    {
     global $data, $db;

     //$sth = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO names VALUES( 0, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
    // $db->execute( $sth, array( $first, $middle, $last, $email ) );

     $data []= array(
       'quetype' => $quetype, 
       'difficulty' => $dif,
       'subject' => $subject,
       'chap' => $chap_name,
       'que' => $que,
       //'ans' => $ans,
       'marks' => $marks

     );
    }

    if(!isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
        echo "";
    }elseif($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
    {
     $dom = DOMDocument::load( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
     $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'Row' );
     $first_row = true;
     foreach ($rows as $row)
     {
       if ( !$first_row )
       {
         $quetype = "";
         $dif = "";
         $subject = "";
         $chap_name = "";
         $que = "";
         //$ans = "";
         $marks = "";

         $index = 1;
         $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName( 'Cell' );
         foreach( $cells as $cell )
         {
           $ind = $cell->getAttribute( 'Index' );
           if ( $ind != null ) $index = $ind;

           if ( $index == 1 ) $quetype = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 2 ) $dif = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 4 ) $subject = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 6 ) $chap_name = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 8) $que = $cell->nodeValue;
           //if ( $index == 9) $ans = $cell->nodeValue;
           if ( $index == 9) $marks = $cell->nodeValue;

           $index += 1;
         }
         add_person($quetype,$dif, $subject,$chap_name,$que,$marks);

         if(isset($_POST['add_que'])){    

                 $chap_sel_std = $_POST['chap_sel_std'];
                 echo $simquefnt = $_POST['sel_f_gn_que'];

                    //que_id    quetype_id    chap_id    sub_id    std_id    que    dif_id    marks    que_cdate
             //$chap_sel_std = $_POST['chap_sel_std']; //que_id    quetype_id    chap_id    sub_id    std_id    que    dif_id    marks    que_cdate
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
                          s_question
                          VALUES (null,'$quetype','$chap_name','$subject','$chap_sel_std','$que','NO IMAGE','$dif','$marks','$simquefnt','$current')");                                                        
    //         header("location:../admin/quetionaris.php#tabs-que"); 
         echo "Successfully Added";
          }
       }
       $first_row = false;
     }
    }
    ?>
```